# Framer Motion : How to animate onboarding component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

Ok , I'm building a Onboarding component with reactjs and framer motion , It's working fine. I just have to animate the highlight component (The component which is highlighting the elements of my web app)

This is what my return looks like

```
  <>
      <Box
        position="absolute"
        w="100vw"
        h="100%"
        zIndex={'overlay'}
        background="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
        mixBlendMode="hard-light"
        overflow={'hidden'}
        id="onboarding-modal"
      >
        <Box pos={'absolute'} ref={holeRef} background={'gray'}></Box>
      </Box>
      <Box w={'100vw'} h={'100%'} zIndex={'popover'} pos={'absolute'}>
        <Box
          pos={'relative'}
          bg="_white"
          h="10px"
          w="10px"
          transform={'rotate(45deg)'}
          ref={popoverArrowRef}
        />
        <Box
          w={'fit-content'}
          pos={'relative'}
          bg={'_white'}
          ref={popoverRef}
          borderRadius="md"
        >
          <Box maxW="90vw" w="300px" p={5}>
            <VStack alignItems={'start'}>
              <Heading as="h4" st={steps[currentStep].title} />
              <Text st={steps[currentStep].content} />
              <HStack justifyContent={'space-between'} w="full">
                <Text fontWeight="medium">
                  {currentStep + 1}/{steps.length}
                </Text>
                <Box>
                  {currentStep > 0 && (
                    <Button mr="2" asLink onClick={() => handlePreviousStep()}>
                      Previous
                    </Button>
                  )}
                  <Button primary onClick={() => handleNextStep()}>
                    Next
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </HStack>
            </VStack>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </>
```

This is how I'm handling my clicks

```
const getPosition = () => {
    const step = steps[stepRef.current]
    if (!step || typeof window !== 'object') return
    const triggerElement = document.getElementById(step.id)

    if (
      triggerElement &&
      popoverRef.current &&
      popoverArrowRef.current &&
      holeRef.current
    ) {
      const triggerElementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(triggerElement)
      const triggerRect = triggerElement.getBoundingClientRect()
      const popoverRefStyle = popoverRef.current.style
      const popoverArrowRefStyle = popoverArrowRef.current.style

      holeRef.current.style.left = `${triggerRect.left}px`
      holeRef.current.style.top = `${triggerRect.top + window.scrollY}px`
      holeRef.current.style.width = `${triggerRect.width}px`
      holeRef.current.style.height = `${triggerRect.height}px`
      holeRef.current.style.borderRadius =
        triggerElementStyle.getPropertyValue('border-radius')

      const popoverWidth = popoverRef.current.offsetWidth

      let popoverLeft =
        triggerRect.left + triggerRect.width / 2 - popoverWidth / 2
      const popoverTop = triggerRect.bottom + window.scrollY + 5

      if (popoverLeft + popoverWidth > window.innerWidth) {
        popoverLeft = triggerRect.left - popoverWidth + triggerRect.width
      }

      if (popoverLeft < 0) {
        popoverLeft = triggerRect.left
      }

      popoverRefStyle.left = `${popoverLeft}px`
      popoverRefStyle.top = `${popoverTop}px`

      popoverArrowRefStyle.top = `${popoverTop + 5}px`
      popoverArrowRefStyle.left = `${
        triggerRect.left + triggerRect.width / 2
      }px`

      window.scrollTo({
        top: popoverTop - window.innerHeight / 2,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      })
    }
  }
```

I just want my div with ref = "holeRef" to flow (in terms of position , width ) rather that pain jumps

Please Help